# How to install Bing weather in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I Googled a lot to find how to download and install the weather feature in Windows 8. I am not having it in my app list. Please tell me how can I add it? I am not finding it in the store available in start menu. I found that it is one of the best applications which win8 have included. Hence I want to make use of it.

Comment: Have you tried searching for "Weather"? I had this application on my Start screen right after installation.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Yeah first thing what I did was searching for weather in start screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 8 contains the Bing Weather feature. The application was not correctly installed. This problem can be solved easily with the feature `Refresh`. Refreshing the PC takes a bit time but puts all the settings to default.

Answer (score 3):

Overall concept use Window 8's own search.
**Key Point** put the focus on 'Store' not 'Apps'.
From the Metro UI Type 'Weather', remember to put the focus on 'Store'.
You could refine the search with 'Bing Weather'

[image: Search for Bing Weather]

Tip for Windows 8 weather apps. Install at least 3 and see which is the best for your needs.

Comment: On my Windows 8 machine "Weather" came as part of the Start screen. http://allthingsd.com/files/2011/06/Windows-8-start-menu.png I am not certain, but I imagine Microsoft's "Weather" app would be powered by Bing.

Comment: I didn't find this weather in store. I am running an enterprise edition.

Answer (score 1):

The official store link for the Windows 8 (Bing) Weather app is [this](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-US/app/weather/421ba874-f903-4965-9b82-d60f3ba3cae0)

Click in Internet Explorer 10 in Windows 8 and the store will download the right app. (The app name is localized to your system Language, you won't find it as "Bing Weather")